# Vuex not reactive when I commit from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have `Product` component and its nested component, called `Filter`.

In `Product` component I list all products.

```
// Product Component

// Scripts
        computed: {
            products() {
                return this.$store.getters.getServerData.products;
            },
            ...mapGetters({
                serverData: 'getServerData'
            })
        },

//Template
<div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" class="w-full md:w-1/3 px-3">

     <product-item :product="product"></product-item>

</div>

<attribute-filter :attributes="serverData.attributes"></attribute-filter> // Filter
```

When I filter products, I put filtered products into a new array and commit to set that array to state.

```
// Filter Component

<script>
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        props: ['option', 'attribute'],
        computed: {
            products() {
                return this.$store.getters.getServerData.products;
            },
            ...mapGetters({
                filters: 'attribute/getFilters',
                serverData: 'getServerData'
            })
        },
        methods: {
            toggleFilter(option) {
                option.attributeCode = this.attribute.code;

                this.$store.dispatch('attribute/toggleFilter', option);

                let filteredProducts = this.products.filter((product) => {
                      // Logic code to filter product                   
                      ....
                });

                let data = this.serverData;
                data['products'] = filteredProducts;

                this.$store.commit('setData', data);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

After I set the new array data to state, the computed `products` and `serverData` in `Product` component aren't reactive. I tried to print then out, what I got is `undefined`.

And I got this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined"

found in

---> <ProductPage> at resources/js/components/Product/ProductPage.vue
       <App> at resources/js/components/App.vue
```

Comment: can you create a sasndbox

Comment: Check your serverData getter. I suppose it returns undefined

Comment: @Manu Yes, it returns undefined but before I filter it still works. Only return undefined after I filter.

Comment: First of all you have to resolve issue with getter, because this line `let data = this.serverData;` block your code.
Can you share this getServerData getter?

Comment: @Manu here is my code: const getters = {
    getLoading: state => {
        return state.loading;
    },

    getServerData: state => {
        return state.serverData;
    }
};

Comment: You can simplify your functions like `getServerData: state => state.serverData`

Comment: But getter is looking ok. You have to check you action and mutation. Somewhere serverData getting undefined